# Wait Operation Timed Out When Connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, remote-access

I'm having a hell of a hard time trying to figure out why I can connect to my SQL Server using Management Studio using my local ip or local computer name or sql instance name but I can't connect to the same SQL Server using my public ip address.

I have tried all of the below steps but nothing seems to fix the Wait Operation Timed Out error message:

1. Disabled firewall on the SQL Server and the computer I'm trying to use to connect with.
2. Port forwarding is enabled for the port I'm using which is the default 1433
3. Ran the telnet command: telnet publicip port from a computer outside of my network and it was successful
4. Restarted the SQL Server plenty of times
5. Enabled remote connections for the server and enabled tcp/ip for the 1433 port
6. I also enabled port forwarding for the sql browser service using the recommended port of 1434 via udp
7. Tried to connect with named instance but only works with local ip and not public ip

I am pretty much out of ideas at this point so any help is greatly appreciated

Here is the full error message just in case anyone needs to see it:

Cannot connect to XX.XX.XXX.XXX,1433.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

Comment: Did you provide the instance name? I wouldn't leave the FW off for any length of time, and wouldn't open SQL to the internet at all

Comment: Yes I tried using the instance name as well and like everything I have tried, it works with my local ip but not using my external public ip. I'm running a small sql server that needs to be open to the public but once I have this working, I will enable a whitelist for ip addresses and enable the firewall

Comment: Check all the ports line up. You have 1434 and udp as the port forward, should be 1433 tcp

Comment: @Charlieface I edited my post to clarify that I also port forwarded 1434 udp for the sql browser service. I have port 1433 tcp port forwarded for the sql server